# iptables DROP all access except my dynamic IP, is it possible and how/workaround?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall, dynamic-ip

If not possible, is there any workaround without affecting CPU performance?

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use static ip but DHCP, you can filter on mac address in iptables.
Something like :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -m mac --mac-source 00:0F:EA:91:04:07 -j ACCEPT
```

With your workstation mac address.

Have a look here : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-mac-address-filtering.html

Hope this help !

Comment: This will only work if both machines are in the same subnet.

Comment: @mulaz: wow bad...i didn't know that :( I use this in my job but you are right, hosts are in same subnet...

Comment: I did not test, but I believe it works. Perhaps any iptables workaround when not shared the same network?